# Large number of KV operations(insert, upsert) on a couchbase bucket leads to concurrent.timeout.Exception

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view, couchbase-java-api

I am trying to insert/upsert documents into couchbase database using Java JDK client 2.4.7 and couchbase server 5.0.1. The couchbase cluster is setup on AWS EC2 with 6 data nodes of type m4.2xLarge and two index/query nodes of type m4.xLarge.

The documents count(records) to be inserted into couchbase is about 6 millions. These records are group together into chunks of 10K each. 20 worker threads are performing insert/upsert operation for each chunk of 10K by iterating over each record using a for loop. The time taken for insertion of each chunk keeps on increasing over a regular interval, eventually leading to the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.couchbase.client.java.util.Blocking.blockForSingle(Blocking.java:77)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.subdoc.MutateInBuilder.execute(MutateInBuilder.java:280)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.subdoc.MutateInBuilder.execute(MutateInBuilder.java:103)
    at com.onkaar.XXXXXXXX.kernel.infrastructure.data.CouchbaseSaveAccountRepository.saveBatch(CouchbaseSaveAccountRepository.java:56)
    at com.onkaar.XXXXXXXX.kernel.storage.StorageTask.executeTask(StorageTask.java:38)
    at com.onkaar.XXXXXXXX.kernel.storage.StorageTask.run(StorageTask.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Following are the environment configuration I am using for connecting to the couchbase cluster:
Couchbase IO Pool Size = 5;
Computation pool Size = 5;
KV Endpoint Count = 3;
KV Timeout = 5000;
Connection Timeout = 10000;
Worker Threads = 20;

Can you please suggest optimal configuration for this use case.